# Can we Store result set post recursive CTE error of maximum recursion

Tags: sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I want to capture result set into table of recursive query post having maximum recursion error on query.
Tried insert result set into a temp but unable to find way out for same.

```sql
BEGIN TRY WITH NumbersCTE AS (
  SELECT 1 AS Number'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Number + 1 FROM NumbersCTE WHERE  Number < 40000
) insert into temp23 
SELECT * FROM   NumbersCTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100) END TRY BEGIN CATCH
SELECT SUSER_SNAME(),ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_STATE(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_PROCEDURE(), 
  ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;
```

Comment: No, you can't. The statement fails within the CTE,and so dataset is generated as the expression doesn't finish evaluating.

Comment: You appear to have a floating single quote in your query...

Comment: Also worth noting that the normal way to fix it - increasing the maxrecursion number to allow an insert to work - isn't possible here as it has a maximum value of 32767.